# How to create a cumulative max for a date column

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame (or data.table) with a column of dates. I want to create a new column with the maximum date for all the preceding records(not including the current record)

Thanks.

The following code creates a column(premax) which contains the max value (cummax) of 'end' for the rows up to and including the current row. I would like to do this where 'end' is a date variable. I would also like to be able exclude the current row(think sql's row bounding).It appears cumsum does not support date types.

```
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union


id<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
start<-c(1,2,3,4,2,3, 4,5)
end<-  c(2,5,4,7,4,10,6,12)

df<-data.frame(id,start,end)


df %>% mutate(premax=cummax(end))
#>   id start end premax
#> 1  1     1   2      2
#> 2  1     2   5      5
#> 3  1     3   4      5
#> 4  1     4   7      7
#> 5  2     2   4      7
#> 6  2     3  10     10
#> 7  2     4   6     10
#> 8  2     5  12     12
```

Comment: This is in R Sorry for the incomplete question. (Got caught in my own little world).

Comment: please, give at least an example dataset, see [mcve], so people can answer precisely.

Answer (score -1):

Your description is not complete

If you are in SQL, a DateTime2 type column is suggested

If it is json, you can add a new value to all of them by scrolling